# Need to be able to select on a column that can have one ore more values

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, multi-select

I have a column in a sharepoint list that lists the various departments within my company.  One or more of these departments can be selected.  Since the column does not show up as a selection when I try to use the default "group" functionality in SharePoint I exported the list to Excel hoping to get the data I want.

First column is a text column with the name of a test. The second column is the name of the group testing,  this is a multi select column since multiple groups could be doing the same test. The third column is status column,  Pass, Fail, Pending

I have done a `countif()` function to count the number of reports each group has on it's plate.

```
=COUNTIF(User_Group,"*" & A6 & "*")
```

and this works fine. When I try to do a sumproduct function I am running into issues with how to phrase the query.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((User_Group="*"&A6&"*")*(Test_Status="Pending"))
```

using the Countif you use a , to designate the criteria, in `SUMPRODUCT` you use <, >, or an = sign to designate. Since I am trying to designate on an "Contains" and not an = I am at a loss about how to make this work.

I would like to count how many accepted or rejected tests each group has currently. Any ideas?